# Only first item listed in Xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

When ran only the first item in my xml is showing the table. how can i get it so that it will list all of the items in the App node?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Chris Martin-->
<Software>
<Company Name="Microsoft">
  <App>
    <AppItem Price="$79.99" Version="2016" MultiOs="true" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="2">Office Word</AppItem>
    <AppItem Price="$109.99" Version="2016" MultiOs="true" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="2">Office PowerPoint</AppItem>
    <AppItem Price="$458.93" Version="2015" MultiOs="false" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="2">Office Visual Studio</AppItem>
    <AppItem Price="$149.99" Version="4" MultiOs="false" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="2">Expression Web</AppItem>
    <AppItem Price="$109.99" Version="2016" MultiOs="true" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="2">Office Excel</AppItem>
  </App>
</Company>
<Company Name="Adobe">
  <App>
    <AppItem Price="$19.99/mo" Version="CC" MultiOs="true" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="2">Photoshop</AppItem>
    <AppItem Price="$19.99/mo" Version="CC" MultiOs="true" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="2">Dreamweaver</AppItem>
    <AppItem Price="$19.99/mo" Version="CC" MultiOs="true" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="2">Premiere Pro</AppItem>
    <AppItem Price="$19.99/mo" Version="CC" MultiOs="true" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="2">After Affects</AppItem>
    <AppItem Price="$19.99/mo" Version="CC" MultiOs="true" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="2">InDesign</AppItem>
  </App>
</Company>
<Company Name="Apple">
  <App>
    <AppItem Price="$299.99" Version="10.2.2" MultiOs="false" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="3">Final Cut Pro</AppItem>
    <AppItem Price="$199.99" Version="10.2" MultiOs="false" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="3">Logic Pro X</AppItem>
  </App>
</Company>
<Company Name="Mars">
  <App>
    <AppItem Price="Free" Version="4.5.1" MultiOs="true" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="5">Eclipse</AppItem>
  </App>
</Company>
<Company Name="JetBrains">
  <App>
    <AppItem Price="$199.99" Version="15.0.2" MultiOs="true" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="3">IntelliJ IDEA</AppItem>
  </App>
</Company>
<Company Name="Broderbund">
  <App>
    <AppItem Price="$99.99" Version="4.0" MultiOs="false" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="3">Print Shop Pro 4</AppItem>
  </App>
</Company>
</Software>
```

Xslt:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Saftware Database</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Software Titles</h1>

        <table Border="2">
          <tr>
            <th>Vedor</th>
            <th>Softwar Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Version</th>
            <th>MultiOs</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="Software/Company">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="App/AppItem"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="App/AppItem/@Price"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="App/AppItem/@Version"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="App/AppItem/@MultiOs"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a screen shot of the output that im getting

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuvgY.png)

Comment: you have to loop over AppItem as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:for-each select="Software/Company/App/AppItem">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../@Name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Price"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Version"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@MultiOs"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

To sort by price, you must first remove all non-numerical characters from the price:

```
 <xsl:sort select="translate(@Price, translate(@Price, '.0123456789', ''), '')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
```

Comment: How could i change this to sort it by price? I have used the <xsl:sort statement but it just uses the first numbers to sort it.

Comment: @DarthMactis See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm ty!!